# Error in X[, colnames, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

```
library(rms)
x<-c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")
y<-c(-340,-310,-289,-189,-300)
z<-c(1,0,1,0,1)
data<-data.frame(x,y,z)
A.B<-data$x
C.D<-data$y
ef<-data$z
sign<-data.frame(A.B,C.D,ef)

names(sign)<-c("A B","C D","ef")
model<-lrm(ef~.,data=sign)

Error in X[, mmcolnames, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

I replaced the "." with space in the column name.
If I did not rename the column, it would run without Error.

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. List any non-base R packages you are using. I'm guessing it's because of the spaces in the column names which are usually frowned upon. Are they absolutely necessary when fitting the model? It might be better to clean things up afterward.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `library(rms); set.seed(101); dd <- data.frame(ef=sample(0:1,size=20,replace=TRUE),A.B=rnorm(20),C.D=rnorm(20));
m1 <- lrm(ef~., data=dd); names(dd) <- c("A B","C D","ef"); m2 <- lrm(ef~., data=dd)`.  We really do need a [mre] ...

Comment: I have add a minimal reproducible example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error

```r
Error in X[, mmcolnames, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

means that you are selecting something that is out of a range. This range can be the number of rows, columns, or both. Unfortunately, you also get this error when you are not naming your rows/columns properly. For example, in `R` you should **never** include spaces in your column or row names - just as variable names ! - because some functions interprete them literally. This is exactly what happens in your case. This line

```r
model <- lrm(ef ~ ., data=sign)
```

attemps to select the columns `A B` and `C D`, observe the missing " ! Of course, this causes problems because spaces are not allowed as a separater for names. So change your script to

```r
library(rms)

x    <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes")
y    <- c(-340, -310, -289, -189, -300)
z    <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
data <- data.frame(x, y, z)

A.B  <- data$x
C.D  <- data$y
ef   < -data$z
sign <- data.frame(A.B, C.D, ef)

# This does the trick!
names(sign) <- c("AB","CD","ef")

model <- lrm(ef ~ .,
             data = sign)
```

and you will be fine.

The rational above also explains your observation here

> I replaced the "." with space in the column name. If I did not rename the column, it would run without Error.

because if you are not (!) renaming your column names with `names(sign) <- c("A B","C D","ef")` you column names would be

```
> sign <- data.frame(A.B, C.D, ef)
> names(sign)
[1] "A.B" "C.D" "ef"
```

which works (see explanation above). So either use this

```r
names(sign) <- c("A.B","C.D","ef")
```

or this

```r
names(sign) <- c("A_B","C_D","ef")
```

Long story shot, **always** use as a separater either `.` or `_`, but never space for names.

HTH

Comment: If you have messy column names, you may find the package [`janitor`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) helpful. For example, `janitor::clean_names(sign)`.